# Express.js: Do background task after sending response to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

It is a simple controller. Receive requests from users, do task and response to them. My goal is to make the response as soon as possible and do the task then so the user will not notice the lengthy waiting time.

Here is my code:

```
router.post("/some-task", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("ok!");
    Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, 5000); // lengthy task
});
```

When post to this controller, I need to wait 5000ms before getting the response, which is not I want. I have tried promise but don't work either. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: maybe remove `5000` ?

Comment: this is just a demonstration for a 5000ms task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Improve version for Evyatar Meged answer:

```
router.post("/some-task", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("ok!");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, 5000); // lengthy task
    }, 0);
});
```

It is not about `res.end`, just `setTimeout` do the thing. But I don't recommend this since it will block the entire app for handling other requests. You may need to think to use `child process` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a callback after `res.end` that will execute as soon as the response was sent.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.end('123', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {console.log('456')}, 5000)
  })
});
```

Notice you're browser will receive `123` and after 5 seconds your server will log `456`.